# Select Datatype based on some condition

Tags: java, android, class, casting, sugarorm

For those who are not using sugarORM in android, what I want is to choose what class datatype should a object have. For example,

```
Class1 c;
If(statuscode==1){
    c = new Class1();
}else if(statuscode==2){
    c = new Class2();
}else if(statuscode==3){
    c = new Class3();
}
```

But this will give my cast error in case 2 and case 3. So, how to solve it ?

In detail, for those who know sugarORM in Android

I am using sugarORM in android and I have a situation where I need to select from all rows from any one of the four table based on some condition, or, I need to do something else.

For Example,

```
List<Table1> list = Table1.listAll(Table1.class);
or
Table1 t = new Table1();
```

Now, based on status code of an Intent I am receiving, I need to use Table1, Table2, Table3 or Table4

Means, I need to use either

```
List<Table1> list = Table1.listAll(Table1.class);
or
List<Table2> list = Table2.listAll(Table2.class);
or
List<Table3> list = Table3.listAll(Table3.class);
or
List<Table4> list = Table4.listAll(Table4.class);
```

How can I do that ?

What I tried is, to use switch case everywhere in my code wherever I need to list all rows or instantiate a new object of that Table

```
        List<Table1> list=null;
        switch (statuscode){ //statuscode in Integer 1,2,3,4
            case 1:
                list = Table1.listAll(Table1.class);
                break;
            case 2:
                list = Table2.listAll(Table2.class);
                break;
            case 3:
                list = Table3.listAll(Table3.class);
                break;
        }
```

But obviously case 2 and case 3 will give cast error

So, whats the solution for this type of problem ?

Comment: why can't you use an `interface`

Comment: Yeah. define an interface `A`, let your three classes implement `A` and declare `c` as `A` like this: `A c;`

Comment: Create a class named Table. Then let Table1,2 and 3 implement this one.

Comment: @Scary Wombat Let me try it, and will inform you then

Comment: @AhmadWabbi Let me try it, and will inform you then

Comment: @Wesley De Keirsmaeker Let me try it, and will inform you then

Answer (score 0):

One obvious solution is to use a base class. You can use something like

```
List<Object> list
```

instead of

```
List<Table1> list
```

or as scary wombat suggested, have the 4 classes implement an interface and use that interface when defining the list.

Comment: Let me try it and will inform u then